# How to Add/remove row in table in jquery when we check and uncheck the checkbox in other table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one table where i have select the row by checking check box. I wanted to add selected checkbox rows to another table which is dynamically created when some one check checkbox.

I am waiting for you response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
$("#firsttableid input:checkbox").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").appendTo("#yoursecondtableid");
});
```

***Edit***

If you dont' want to move the row then you can use **[.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** to the row and then append to the other table like. Also a change in the click handler to not add the row when the checkbox is unchecked. If you don't want to add a row again and again you have to take care of that too.

```
$("#firsttableid input:checkbox").click(function(){
    if ($ (this).is(":checked"))
    {
        $(this).closest("tr").clone().appendTo("#yoursecondtableid");
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/obani)**

**[Working Demo with remove](http://jsbin.com/obani/3)**

Comment: the above code will remove the column from existing table and add to another table i wanted that it will not remove it just add to new table 
thanks

Comment: Going great but the problem is this when some one uncheck the check button it also remove from the location?

Comment: Working Demo : I see your working demo. But i need when some one check it add to the table and when some one un checked  main table it is also remove from the parent table (which is dynamically created by the user)

Comment: Great Rahul. Thanks dude Going great. You have great future ahead. Best Of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Basically as rahul suggested but a minor addition adding **clone()**

```
$('#first_table_id input:checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo('#second_table_id');
});
```

[Jquery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) is your friend :)

Comment: This will add the row when the checkbox is unchecked also.